# PySpark filter by dataframe column

Tags: join, filter, pyspark

I recently started with PySpark, so I am complete beginner. What I want to do is filter from one dataframe based on another dataframe.
To put it simple, I have df1 with columns A,B,C and df2 with column A. I want to output only df1 rows that have A column values within df2 values.

Currently I have it set up as following:

```py
df_final = df1.join(df2, df2.A == df1.A)
```

What I found online also is following solution:

```py
df_final = df1.join(df2, Seq("A"), "left_anti")
```

It seems that it does the same thing, but I wonder which one is more correct/better performing?

At the same time, I found also that `.filter` can be used, but I have no idea how to use it dataframe/list.

Main question actually is - what is the best way to perform this task to run the job as fast as possible?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Note, `Seq` is not available inside `Python`.

```
df_final = df1.join(df2, Seq("A"), "left_anti")
```

Assume `df1` has the following content

```
+---+----+-----+
|  A|   B|    C|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|John|Smith|
|  2|Praz| June|
|  3|hell|valu3|
|  4|test|valu2|
+---+----+-----+
```

And `df2` has

```
+---+
|  A|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
```

When you do this

```
df_final = df1.join(df2, df2.A == df1.A)
```

It will now **Warn!!** you with:

> constructing trivially true equals predicate, 'A#154L = A#154L'. Perhaps you need to use aliases.

This implies that you are trying to join two `DataFrame` having same `column`.

You said,

> I want to output only df1 rows that have A column values within df2 values.

You can select `df1` rows from column A using `.select()` i.e.

```
df1_A = df1.select('A')
```

Then, you can `join()` using

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col  
df_final = df1_A.alias('le').join(df2.alias('ri'), (col('le.A') == col('ri.A')))
```

- **col**: Returns a Column based on the given column name.

Regarding filter, you can use filter when you want evaluate based on some condition. For more information, refer:
[class DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html)